# Change content like Google Drive

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'd like to change the content of my website like google dirve does.
Example: Google Drive start with the URL drive/my-drive. If I click in the navigation on recent, the URL changes to drive/recent.

I tried to achive the same result using `<a href="#name">`. But with this solution the URL changes to something like .../index.html#name

How can I get the same result as Google?

Answer (score 0):

The links "URL drive/my-drive" and URL drive/recent" are different pages.
What `<a href="#name">` does is try to send you to a tag with id="name" on the same page.

> You have to create two pages and put a hyperlink in one html to
>   another page using a base URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)! But why doesn't change the content? If you click "View Source" and change the page using the navigation, the code doesn't change. Plus, if I disable JavaScript the navigation doesn't work anymore. So this must be done with JavaScript, doesn't it?

Comment: Whats is this called? I don't know how to googel my problem.